# How do I install ownCloud client on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, owncloud-client

I searched `ownCloud` on Ubuntu Software Center on Ubuntu **12.04** and only got `Empty package, owncloud`.

I also checked it on the offcial installation guide, [here](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:desktop&package=owncloud-client). The lowest supported version is **14.04**.

I downloaded [Packages for Ubuntu 14.04: `owncloud-client_2.2.2-18.1_amd64.deb`](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_14.04/amd64/owncloud-client_2.2.2-18.1_amd64.deb), but failed to install it for,

[image]

**How do I install ownCloud client on Ubuntu 12.04?**

---

The output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`,

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable main
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_12.04/ /
```

Comment: Try to actually add the 14.04 repository, not just download individual 14.04 pckages.

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

Comment: @Dorian, thx for ur constant help. I just added it.

Comment: Great, looks like it's correct. Have you tried the my answer below that I changed?

Comment: @Dorian, I didn't try it since I don't have the root access to the lab computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 2.2.0 onwards the ownCloud client was not supposed to be build for 12.04 ([source](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/5032#issuecomment-230719124)), but the last available build for 12.04 is 2.2.1. It is not available on the official download page anymore, but has [a separate repository](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=isv%3AownCloud%3Adesktop%3Aclient-2.2.1&package=owncloud-client) which you can still use to install it.

The installation instructions are on the linked pages, enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

With the updated question, I see now the error about dependencies.

You can try to manually install the missing dependency by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libowncloudsync0
```

When installing libowncloudsync0 you may get errors from other dependencies missing.

Try `sudo apt-get install libqtkeychain0 libqt5keychain0`

And then `libowncloudsync0` again, and finally, the client you were trying to install in the first place.

Sometimes when you get an error like this of unmet dependencies, you can fix them all by simply running `sudo apt-get install -f` after the failed install.

Comment: this is for ubuntu `14.04`, not **12.04**.

Comment: Did you try following the instructions anyway?

Comment: @Dorian, Yes, I failed to install ownCloud using packages for **14.04**, pls check my edited question.